# Disable movement of columns in agGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using AgGrid table in my application. Here is the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/O6ADg9DZEOCREByn). According to the documentation i want to stop movement of the columns. For this i used:

```
suppressMovable: true
```

The above code I used here:

```js
 columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: 'Athlete',  //the generic name of header
          children: [
            {
              field: 'athlete',   //children header from generic header
              width: 150,
              suppressMovable:true
            },
            {
              field: 'age',
              lockVisible: true,
              cellClass: 'locked-visible',
              suppressMovable:true

            },
            {
              field: 'country',
              width: 150,
            },
            { field: 'year' },
            { field: 'date' },
            { field: 'sport' },
          ],
          ...
```

`suppressMovable:true`, it works, and the `athlete` and `age` columns aren't possible to be moved like others, but this code also disable the movement of the main column: `Athlete`. So when i try to switch the place of `Athlete` and `Medals` columns, i can't, but i don't want this, i want to set this 2 main columns as movable.
Question: How to disable movement of columns inside the `Athlete` and `Column`, but to keep the movement functionality of these 2 main columns?

Comment: You can fork the project and change this [function](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/community-modules/core/src/ts/headerRendering/headerGroup/headerGroupWrapperComp.ts#L298-L310) to not taking account of the child columns when deciding if the column group movement should be supressed.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box answer is you can't.

If any child is fixed, then AG Grid doesn't allow moving the group.

you can write custom event listener(if possible) to change the `suppressMovable` property of child columns while the parent column is being dragged and then again set them to not movable/`suppressMovable`  to true. else you can programatically move all columns in a group using `moveColumnByIndex(from,to)`

Comment: how  to add an event listener when i try to move these 2 main columns?

Comment: could you take a look, please?

Comment: sure give me some time.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow properties to lock the drag and drop behavior: lockPosition and suppressMovable: true.

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
  {
    field: 'athlete',
    suppressMovable: true,
    cellClass: 'suppress-movable-col',
  },
  { field: 'age', lockPosition: 'left', cellClass: 'locked-col' },
  { field: 'country' },
  { field: 'year' },
  { field: 'total', lockPosition: 'right', cellClass: 'locked-col' 
},
]);
const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
   return {
     flex: 1,
     lockPinned: true, // Dont allow pinning for this example
   };
  }, []);
```

[Sample in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrLaRNoHzlCkn6Nc?open=index.jsx)
[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-moving/)